# Adding an image to a video, but the video isn't playing after addition

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I was editing a video, and wanted to add some images which should appear at the top and bottom of the respective video.

But once I added an image, made transformations to make it appear where I want, I cannot see the video when I play the sequence. It is just the image I see with a black and grey crossed background.

When I remove the "Trasnform" strip of the image, I am able to see the video along with the image. But I cannot place the image as I wish.

Any solutions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "replace"-blend mode to "alpha over" or whatever your default is there in items like here:

[image: blend mode]

Also you can resize your image/video in the settings and place them via x,y.

Just tap on your video, then go to effect-strip -> transform like this:

[image]

Here you can set x/y and the size...and don't forget to change blend to alpha over again.

[image]